# gather information about packet from malicious ip

Tags: linux, networking, security, linux-networking, network-monitoring

I have a glassfish server running some webservice and I noticed that there is an abnormal traffic from japan (150.70.x.x) in my iptables log file and I dont have any user in this country .
Until now this IPs didn't succed to connect to my webservice .
Project honeypot detected this IPs as malicious so I want to dig more and understand what this hacker is trying to do .

How can I log the **full** packet from those IPs to analyse them ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Solved with tcpdump :

```
tcpdump -i eth0 -w honey.out -s 0 net 150.0.0.0/8
```